# Using Jquery Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have been using a JQuery Masonry script for quite some time, with no problems at all. That is with heights that do not change after page load. Now, I am using JQuery to hide/show content (after the page has already loaded) but the JQuery Masonry does not accommodate for the new heights. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I am using:

```
jQuery Masonry v2.1.05
```

By:

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/
```

My JQUERY to select the elements:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $container = $('#timeline-posts-wrap');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.post-wrap'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to rerun the `.masonry({...});` function each time you hide/show content for it to be rearranged.